# PHP Serialization and Inheritance

Tags: php, serialization

Not sure what the process is for serializing a child class that is implementing the `Serializable` interface, the parent class no longer retains the data it was once serializing. Is there a step I am missing?

```
class A {
    private $aVar = "test";
}

class B extends A implements Serializable {
    private static $bVar = "tset";

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(self::$bVar);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        self::$bVar = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}

$s = serialize(new B());
$u = unserialize($s);
```

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is create a static variable in the child class, but since serialization does not handle static variables, I was attempting to serialize just this myself; here, i'll go ahead and change that on here now so better reflects the scenario. Maybe the title should be how to serialize a static variable in a child class?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused as to what's happening here, but essentially what you're seeing is incorrectly scoped variables.

- **Public variables**, are variables that are **visible to all classes**
- **Private variables**, are variables that are **visible only to the class to which they belong**.
- **Protected variables**, are variables that are **visible only to the class to which they belong, and any subclasses**.

If you were to make `$aVar` in `Class A` protected or public you'd be able to access it in `Class B`:

You would get the following:

```
B Object
(
    [bVar:B:private] => tset
    [aVar] => test
)
```

Comment: but I don't want to access it; if I were to remove the `Serializable` interface and corresponding the methods, everything is serialized perfectly fine.